# the default table name is "votes" for gem acts_as_votable, can I change to whatever name I want? and how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, acts-as-votable

The default table name is "voter" for gem acts_as_votable, how can I change the table name to whatever I want?

It conflicts with another table name of mine.

Comment: how can I override the default table name, "votes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just searched through the gem documentation and I don't see it has any option like that.

You may have to change the table name that's conflicted with the gem if you still wanna use this.

Otherwise, you can build the feature from scratch by this gem's implementation, but I don't think that's a good idea.